# Relation of random variable to outcome of trials

Tags: probability

If we have many Random Variables $X^i$s then is there any relation between trials performed to get values of $X$ and i? For example in machine learning we say $X^i$s are feature vectors, then is $X^i$ the value of $X$ in the ith trial?